# Optimization Problem on Excel: How many project can be conducted over a year?

Tags: excel, optimization

I'm probably pushing Excel to its limits, but here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a firm with the following inputs for one year:

1. N project (Pi) to conduct. Each project is broken into activities (Aj(Pi)). For example, a project can be "building a house" and activities can be "construction", "plumbing", "electricity"...
   Each project has an estimated total of man-days per activity. Which means I basically have a table in Excel:

   P1 A1 4 md

   P1 A2 10 md

   P1 A3 5 md

   P2 A1 20 md
   ...

Projects are sorted from most important to least important.

2. M employees (Ei) who can work on several projects. Each employee is part of a single community (Cj) and is assigned total available man-days for a year (usually around 220 md). Which means I have a table in Excel:

   E1 C3 220

   E2 C1 210

   E3 C2 219
   ....
3. Each community (Cj) is linked to several activities its members can perform. For example, the community "electricians" is linked to activities likes "Electricity", "Lighting", "Inspection"...Which means I have a table in Excel:

   C1 A1

   C1 A2

   C1 A3

   C2 A2

   C3 A1
   ...

My question is:

A) Given my employees and their abilities, how many projects can I conduct over the year? And what's the corresponding allocation?

B) Is it possible to do this on Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel Solver Add-in. It can solve optimization problems such as this.

Here's information on Microsoft Excel Support page for the Excel Solver Add-in (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/load-the-solver-add-in-in-excel-612926fc-d53b-46b4-872c-e24772f078ca)

Comment: Managed to succeed with the Solver add-in. Thanks!